# Path is drawn again after submit, how to clear previous path?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

fellow newbie in google maps API and stackoverflow.

I am creating an app where I can draw multiple routes on the map. At first, there's only one textbox and if I type an address and click the "calculate" button, it works fine. 
However, if I click it again the path is drawn again. (The path is dark blue, meaning there's a blue route on top of another)

Is there a way to somehow refresh the map or clear the path that was previously drawn?

My code is something like this. I wrote it in such a way that the textboxes' values are added to an array and this array is what I'll use to calculate the route.

```
form.onsubmit = function () {
        //var okay = true;
        var userAddressArray = [];
        $("input.address").each(function( index ) {
        userAddressArray.push($(this).val());

        });
        num = 1;
        for(var i=0; i < userAddressArray.length; i++){
            directionsVisible = false;
            destination = userAddressArray[i];
            calcRoute(destination, num); 
            num = num + 1;

        }

        return false; 
    }
```

**Here's my calcRoute function:**

```
   function calcRoute(inputAddress, number) {
        if (!geocoder) {
            geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        }

        var geocoderRequest = {
            address: inputAddress
        }

        geocoder.geocode(geocoderRequest, function (results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);

                destinationLoc = new google.maps.LatLng(results[0].geometry.location.lat(), results[0].geometry.location.lng());
                //var dest = new google.maps.LatLng(results[0].geometry.location.lat(), results[0].geometry.location.lng());

             // compare this to an array of pre-loaded points
                getClosestPath(destinationLoc); 
             //drawing the path
               requestDirections(closest, destinationLoc, inputAddress, destinationLoc, number);

            }


        });

    }
```

**requestDirections function:**

```
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
```

function requestDirections(start, end, address, number) {

```
clearOverlays();

directionsService.route({
    origin: start,
    destination: end,
    avoidTolls: true,
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.WALKING
}, function (result, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        renderDirections(result, address, number);
    }

    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.NOT_FOUND) {
        alert("One of the locations you entered could not be geocoded.");
    }

    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.ZERO_RESULTS) {
        alert("Invalid address entered, please enter a valid address.");
    }
});
```

}

**renderDirections function:**

```
function renderDirections(result, address, number) {

var myRoute = result.routes[0].legs[0];

for (var i = 0; i < myRoute.steps.length; i++) {
}
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myRoute.steps[i - 1].end_point,
    map: map,
    icon: "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/green-dot.png"

});

  var directionsRenderer = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
        map: map,
        suppressMarkers: true,
        draggable: true
    });
  markersArray.push(marker);

  directionsRenderer.setMap(map);
  //polylineOpts.setMap(map);
  directionsRenderer.setDirections(result);

}
```

I hope this is detailed enough, otherwise, let me know. I hope you can help me with this one!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your directionsRenderer global (your original code creates a new one for every directions request):

```
var directionsRenderer = null;
function renderDirections(result, address, number) {

var myRoute = result.routes[0].legs[0];

for (var i = 0; i < myRoute.steps.length; i++) {
}
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myRoute.steps[i - 1].end_point,
    map: map,
    icon: "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/green-dot.png"

});

  directionsRenderer = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
        map: map,
        suppressMarkers: true,
        draggable: true
    });
  markersArray.push(marker);

  directionsRenderer.setMap(map);
  //polylineOpts.setMap(map);
  directionsRenderer.setDirections(result);

}
```